# How to evaluate the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2^x+1}{2^{x+1}}$

Tags: limits

How to evaluate the limit as it approaches infinity

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2^x+1}{2^{x+1}}$$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**

$\displaystyle \frac{2^x + 1}{2^{x+1}} = \frac{2^x}{2^{x+1}} + \frac{1}{2^{x+1}} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^{x+1}}$

Comment: I see how that works you have to take out a 2 from $2^{x+1}$ so the $2x$ terms will cancel

Comment: I'm glad I could help =D

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2^x+1}{2^{x+1}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2^x}{2^{x+1}}+\frac{1}{2^{x+1}}$ Can you simplify this?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\frac{2^x + 1}{2^{x + 1}} = \frac{1 + 2^{-x}}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $2^{x+1}$ as ${2(2^x)}$, then use L'Hopital's rule.
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2^x\ln2}{2(2^x\ln2)}$$
Result is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Wouldn't you still be left with an infinity over infinity situation because of the 2^x in the numerator and denominator?

Comment: Yes, but now, we can divide numberator and denominator by 2^x*ln(2). I think this is the easiest way.

Comment: Ah I see how that works out now

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=2^x$ therefore $t\to\infty  \ \ \text{as}  \ x\to\infty$ hence $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{2^x+1}{2 \cdot 2^x}=\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\frac{t+1}{2t}=\frac{1}{2}.$$